# Receiving entity instead of quote

Tags: javascript

I am facing an issue with Javascript not allowing me to return data via ajax with single quotes in for the 's at the end of words?

For example, I tried returning
`You don't have enough credit to perform this`

I received
`You don&#039;t have enough credit to perform this`

Why?

Code:

```
function sellStock(businessId, stockId, stockName) {
    var mymodal = $('#sellStockModal');

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxCallUrl + 'api/ajax/stock/' + businessId + '/' + stockId + '/get-modal-content',
        type: "GET",
        error: function(req, message) {
            showErrorNotification('It seems something went wrong, sorry...' + message);
        },
        statusCode: {
            400: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification(response.responseText);
            },
            500: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
             mymodal.find('.modal-body').html(data);
             mymodal.modal('show');
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Share the code please.

Comment: @Beefo Post your code and we'll help you.

Comment: And when you add your code, please *edit your question* to do so - don't add as a comment.

Comment: I've added my code.

Comment: And why are you considering this a BIG BUG as described in your title before I changed to for you? It will show correctly in the page

Comment: It doesn't show correctly in the page, that's the issue..

Answer (score -1):

The reply is correct.

Single quote has unicode #39. See http://www.codetable.net/decimal/39